# Отображать в виде массива

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-shared-preferences

Есть метод, где я сохраняю значения нажатого элемента в моём recyclerView:

```
    private void saveFavorites(int position) {
    String name = personCategories.get(position);
    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.KEY_SP, name);
    editor.apply();
}
```

После чего получаю данные в другом фрагменте следующим образом:

```
    private String getFavorites() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getString(Constants.KEY_SP, null);
}
```

Загвоздка в том, что я получаю лишь один какой-то элемент, на который нажал последнем в списке. Как сделать так, чтобы он отображался в виде массива? 
И все элементы, на которые я нажал, добавлялись во второй фрагмент?

Comment: А что мешает создать синглтоном отдельный класс, который будет хранить эти данные, и любой другой фрагмент или адаптер, или что угодно смогут к нему обратиться, а внутри хранить любые коллекции?

Comment: если честно немного непонятно, я начинающий.
Можно какой то пример? или хотя бы отрывок/начало для старта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант попробуйте Ваши строки преобразовать и сохранить в json в методе saveFavorites с помощью библиотеки gson.

После этого получите Ваши строки JSON в методе getFavorites.

Хороший пример описан [здесь](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/). Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: эм, а поподробней можно как то пожалуйста?)

Comment: @Inkognito добавил пример.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший пример, есть там свои неровности, но в целом понетней стало.

Comment: Только не тяните ради массива строк целый GSON в проект, это как из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja цееелый) прям вот серьезный "отговор". А можно более конструктивно, почему Вам такой пример не подходит? Было бы интересно увидеть более весомое замечание.

Comment: @Morozov, потому что есть `JSONArray`, который не добавляет зависимости (не увеличивает время компиляции), не увеличивает размер APK, не увеличивает количество методов. https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, используйте `getStringSet/putStringSet`.
В первом фрагменте код усложнится, надо будет считать, добавить и перезаписать набор строк.

Comment: Спасибо, пробовал подобный вариант, ну немного не совсем то что я спрашивла, возможно я не до конца разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняется только последнее значение, так как Вы сохраняете все значения с одним ключом и, соответственно, последующая запись перезаписывает предыдущую.

Как (плохой) вариант, можете сохранять список значений, а не одно значение.

Но, вообще говоря, `SharedPreferences` не предназначены для хранения подобного рода данных, о чем Вам уже много раз тут говорили.

Comment: подобного рода это каких?
я в вопросе не вижу какие данные автор собирается хранить. Скорей всего простые строки с именами.

Comment: @Morozov подобного рода - это какие то промежуточные значения позиций с целью передачи между компонентами. Преференсы предназначены для хранения настроек и других данных подобного рода, но никак не для комуникаций, в Android есть более подходящие для этого инструменты и паттерны.

Comment: @pavlofff в принципе согласен, но если это в ознакомительных целях то пойдёт, ну и под "коммуникацией" вы имеете в виду "перепрыгивание" данных по фрагментам?

Answer (score 0):

public class DataManager { //пример синглтона

```
private static List<Data> mDataList;

private static SettingsDataManager sInstance;

private DataManager() {

}

public static DataManager getInstance() {


    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (DataManager.class) {
            mInstance = new DataManager();
        }
    }

    return sInstance;
}



public void saveData(List<Data> data) {

    mDataList = data;

}

public List<Data> restoreData() {

 return mDataList;

}
```

}